# Extracting multiple similar tables in different schemas

Tags: mariadb, etl

I am attempting to extract tables from multiple schemas in the same database. The tables are similar enough that they are easy to identify and work with using meta data queries like this one:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE TABLE_NAME  LIKE 'form_entries%'
```

With the wildcard standing in for the only distinct part of the table. Each of these tables has a similar format, but a differing number of columns.

I can write a Python script to loop the schemas, dump each of the tables I need, then put them all in a single schema.  That's the only approach I have at the moment.

I am somewhat familiar with ETL tools like Kettle, but I don't have the experience to know if there is an ETL workflow, or just a better way of accomplishing this.

**Purpose**

Each of the tables involved contains form submission data. Each table is a different form, so the column names are variable. The ultimate goal is data analysis of the form data.

There are a lot of steps to get to the analysis we want, but we are stuck at the first hurdle of how widely spread out the data is.

Comment: [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please post the task itself - the way which you decide to use for to solve it is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is a table called `TABLES`, thereby avoiding the `DISTINCT`.

The `SELECT` could fetch

```
CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", TABLE, ";")
```

thereby generating the set of SELECTs needed to dump all such tables.  You app code could then perform the generated SELECTs and capture the output.